# Tikz plot divide by minimun

Tags: tikz-pgf, perl, filecontents

I want to normalize my plot by the y minimal value. So I want to divide y by y max.  I have already done before in Gnuplot with a Perl sentence :

```
ymin1 = `perl -e 'print sort { $a<=>$b } <>' < "coord.dat" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

But I don't know if it's possible to use a Perl sentence in tikz, and how ? 
Or if it's possible to get the minimal value with y expr= min(\thisrowno{1})

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{coord.dat}
%  x   y
0    -1
1    -1.5
2    -1.3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot[thin]  table[x index=0,y index=1, , y expr= min(\thisrowno{1}) ] {coord.dat};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thisrow` and `\thisrowno` represents a single value. Think it as `pgfplots` reading through the file line by line (or row by row), plotting point by point. For each row you can access the value in one of the columns using `\thisrow{<column name>}` or `\thisrowno{<column index>}`.